# Downloading dwg to Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I'm in the process of learning the Forge platform.  I'm currently using an example (Jigsawify) written by Kean Walmsley because it most accurately describes my goals.  I'm running into an issue of getting my file to download from an Azure Storage Account to Forge.  The error I receive is "The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format."  My question is how does someone go about troubleshooting HTTP protocol when writing, in this case, a workitem in code?  I can put in a breakpoint to view the workitem, but I'm not versed enough to understand where the flaw is in the HTTP header, or even where to find it.  Is there a specific property of the workitem I should be looking at?  If I could find the HTTP statement, I could test it, but I don't where I should find it.

Or am I just completely off base?

Anyway here's the code.  It's a modified version of what Kean wrote:

```
static void SubmitWorkItem(Activity activity)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Submitting workitem...");

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
                    CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Microsoft.Azure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
        StorageCredentials crd = storageAccount.Credentials;

        CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
        CloudFileShare ShareRef = fileClient.GetShareReference("000scrub");
        CloudFileDirectory rootDir = ShareRef.GetRootDirectoryReference();
        CloudFile Fileshare = rootDir.GetFileReference("3359fort.dwg");


    // Create a workitem

    var wi = new WorkItem()
    {
        Id = "", // Must be set to empty
        Arguments = new Arguments(),
        ActivityId = activity.Id
    };


    if (Fileshare.Exists())
    {
        wi.Arguments.InputArguments.Add(new Argument()
        {
            Name = "HostDwg", // Must match the input parameter in activity
            Resource = Fileshare.Uri.ToString(),
            StorageProvider = StorageProvider.Generic // Generic HTTP download (vs A360)
        });
    }

    wi.Arguments.OutputArguments.Add(new Argument()

    {
        Name = "Results", // Must match the output parameter in activity
        StorageProvider = StorageProvider.Generic, // Generic HTTP upload (vs A360)
        HttpVerb = HttpVerbType.POST, // Use HTTP POST when delivering result
        Resource = null, // Use storage provided by AutoCAD.IO
        ResourceKind = ResourceKind.ZipPackage // Upload as zip to output dir

    });

      container.AddToWorkItems(wi);
      container.SaveChanges();

      // Polling loop

      do
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Sleeping for 2 sec...");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        container.LoadProperty(wi, "Status"); // HTTP request is made here
        Console.WriteLine("WorkItem status: {0}", wi.Status);
      }
      while (
        wi.Status == ExecutionStatus.Pending ||
        wi.Status == ExecutionStatus.InProgress
      );

      // Re-query the service so that we can look at the details provided
      // by the service

      container.MergeOption =
        Microsoft.OData.Client.MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
      wi = container.WorkItems.ByKey(wi.Id).GetValue();

      // Resource property of the output argument "Results" will have
      // the output url

      var url =
        wi.Arguments.OutputArguments.First(
          a => a.Name == "Results"
        ).Resource;

      if (url != null)
        DownloadToDocs(url, "SGA.zip");

      // Download the status report

      url = wi.StatusDetails.Report;

      if (url != null)
        DownloadToDocs(url, "SGA-Report.txt");
    }
```

Any help is appreciated,
Chuck

Answer (score 0):

Azure requires that you specify the x-ms-blob-type header when you upload to a presigned URL. See https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-.net-input.output.sample/blob/master/Program.cs#L167

Comment: So does that mean Blobs are the only file storage type I can use?  I was trying to use the standard SMB 3.0 protocol for file storage.

Comment: So to answer my own question, yes, I believe you can use the standard SMB 3.0 file storage, but by default it's private, where a blob is by default public.  If that's incorrect, someone please tell me.  Regardless, it's easier using a blob.

Comment: So this time I'm attempting to refer to a dwg file sitting in a public folder on a web site I've created.  I can get to it with directly using Google or Postman, but my Workitem always 404's on me with a faileddownload message in the result file.  Is the file path ("InputDwg") in the XrefTreeArgument a simple URL string?  What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

So, I was able to figure out how to download my file from Azure to Forge using Albert's suggestion of moving to a blob service.  Here's the code:

```
static void SubmitWorkItem(Activity activity)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Submitting workitem...");

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
            CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Microsoft.Azure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        CloudBlobClient BlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = BlobClient.GetContainerReference("000scrub");
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("3359fort.dwg");

            // Create a workitem

            var wi = new WorkItem()
    {
        Id = "", // Must be set to empty
        Arguments = new Arguments(),
        ActivityId = activity.Id
    };


    if (blockBlob.Exists())
    {
        wi.Arguments.InputArguments.Add(new Argument()
        {
            Name = "HostDwg", // Must match the input parameter in activity
            Resource = blockBlob.Uri.ToString(),
            StorageProvider = StorageProvider.Generic, // Generic HTTP download (vs A360)
            Headers = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Header>()
                {
                    new Header() { Name = "x-ms-blob-type", Value = "BlockBlob" } // This is required for Azure.
                }

        });
    }

    wi.Arguments.OutputArguments.Add(new Argument()

    {
        Name = "Results", // Must match the output parameter in activity
        StorageProvider = StorageProvider.Generic, // Generic HTTP upload (vs A360)
        HttpVerb = HttpVerbType.POST, // Use HTTP POST when delivering result
        Resource = null, // Use storage provided by AutoCAD.IO
        ResourceKind = ResourceKind.ZipPackage, // Upload as zip to output dir 

    });

      container.AddToWorkItems(wi);
      container.SaveChanges();

      // Polling loop

      do
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Sleeping for 2 sec...");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        container.LoadProperty(wi, "Status"); // HTTP request is made here
        Console.WriteLine("WorkItem status: {0}", wi.Status);
      }
      while (
        wi.Status == ExecutionStatus.Pending ||
        wi.Status == ExecutionStatus.InProgress
      );

      // Re-query the service so that we can look at the details provided
      // by the service

      container.MergeOption =
        Microsoft.OData.Client.MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
      wi = container.WorkItems.ByKey(wi.Id).GetValue();

      // Resource property of the output argument "Results" will have
      // the output url

      var url =
        wi.Arguments.OutputArguments.First(
          a => a.Name == "Results"
        ).Resource;

      if (url != null)
        DownloadToDocs(url, "SGA.zip");

      // Download the status report

      url = wi.StatusDetails.Report;

      if (url != null)
        DownloadToDocs(url, "SGA-Report.txt");
    }
```

What isn't complete is the result section.  The ZIP has nothing in it, but hey, baby steps right?

Thanks Albert.
-Chuck